# how to change Catalog settings of a list by powershell

Tags: list, powershell, cross-site-publishing

I would like to change catalog settings of Pages list to make it act like a Catalog by using powershell. It includes adding Title as "Catalog Item URL Fields" and choosing a Term Set for "Navigation Hierarchy".

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but I had the same issue and I think it's a good thing to share my solution with you.

I've built a function which does the job:

```
function enableCatalog($arrayOfLists)
{
    foreach($list in $arrayOfLists)
    {
        write-host "Enabling catalog on list " $list -foregroundcolor Yellow
        $list.IndexedRootFolderPropertyKeys.Add("PublishingCatalogSettings")
        $list.IndexedRootFolderPropertyKeys.Add("IsPublishingCatalog")

        #Break permission inheritance
        $list.BreakRoleInheritance($true,$true)

        #Enable anonymous to the catalog
        $list.AllowEveryoneViewItems = $true
        $list.AnonymousPermMask64 ="Open, OpenItems, ViewListItems, ViewVersions, ViewFormPages, ViewPages, UseClientIntegration"

        $rootFolder = $list.RootFolder
        $rootFolder.Properties.Add("IsPublishingCatalog", "True") #Activate catalog

        $rootFolder.Update()
        $list.Update()
        write-host "Catalog successfully enabled on " $list -foregroundcolor Green
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$lists = <an array of list objects>

enableCatalog $lists

$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

As far as I've tested it, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you.

http://blogs.if-blueprint.de/petbo/2013/08/20/how-to-enable-a-list-as-a-catalog-in-sharepoint-2013-with-powershell/

Comment: Hi @PetBo and welcome to our site. When you post answers please remember to mention when you promote your own blog. The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, **you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.** Read about expected [behaviour](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Also remember that "link only answers" is of less use for our site, since links tend to die. Add a good summary of your answer and *then* link.